# Checking Clojure pre-conditions without running the function?

Tags: clojure, idioms, preconditions

I have one function that does some (possibly lengthy) work `(defn workwork [x] ...)` and some other functions to check if the call will succeed ahead of time `(defn workwork-precondition-1 [x] ...)`.

The precondition functions should be evaluated every time `workwork` is called (e.g. using `:pre`). The precondition functions should also be collected (and:ed) in a single function and made available to client code directly (e.g. to disable a button).

Which is the idiomatic way to solve this in Clojure while avoiding code duplication?

In particular, is there any way to evaluate the pre-conditions of a function without running the function body?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just collect your preconditions into a function:

```
(defn foo-pre [x]
  (even? x))
```

Then call the function in a `:pre`-style precondition:

```
(defn foo [x]
  {:pre [(foo-pre x)]}
  …)
```

For functions introduced using `defn`, you can extract the `:pre`-style preconditions from the metadata on the Var:

```
(-> #'foo meta :arglists first meta)
;= {:pre [(foo-pre x)]}
```

And similarly for the `:arglists` entries for any other arities.

There are two caveats here:

1. The automatically-generated `:arglists` entry in the Var's metadata maybe be overridden. Overriding `:arglists` results in the above kind of useful automatically-generated metadata to be thrown out.
2. The `{:pre [(foo-pre x)]}` value returned by the above `(-> #'foo meta …)` expression contains `foo-pre` as a literal *symbol* – it'd be your responsibility to figure out which function it referred to at `foo`'s point of definition. (This may or may not be possible – for example `foo` could be `defn`'d inside a top-level `let` or `letfn` form, with `foo-pre` a local function.)

And finally, anonymous functions may use `:pre` and `:post`, but there is currently no mechanism for extracting them from the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

to evaluate the function precondition without running the function body,you can use `robert-hooke` library https://github.com/technomancy/robert-hooke/

```
    (use 'robert.hooke)

    (defn workwork [x] ...)

    (defn workwork-precondition-1 
      [f x]
      (if (precondition-1-satisfied? x)
        (f x)
        :precondition-1-not-satisfied))

    (add-hook #'workwork #'workwork-precondition-1)
```