# Clojure: check if a function has certain post (or pre) conditions

Tags: validation, clojure

**Question**

In Clojure, it is possible to check if a variable represents a function, using [ifn?](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ifn_q).

What I'm asking myself is, if there is a way to check if a var is a function which has certain post (or pre) conditions.

Bonus: is it possible to construct the post-condition to be checked parametrically?

**Example**

Let's say that `foo` represents a function (i.e. `(ifn? foo)` returns `true`).
How can I check that `foo` has a certain post condition, e.g. that it returns numbers between `0` and `10`. In other words, how can I check that `foo` has the following post-condition?

`{:post (and (number? %) (<= 0 %) (<= % 10))`

Bonus: is it possible to check for `N`, instead of `10`, where `N` is a parameter I can choose?

`{:post (and (number? %) (<= 0 %) (<= % 10))`

**Background**

I'm [implementing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187050/bloom-filter-implementation-in-clojure) Bloom-filter [data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter), and it would be really nice if I could validate the hash-functions. (I.e., that they are functions returning only numbers between `0` and the number of `bits` in the Bloom-filter.)

**Remarks**

I'm already aware of some workarounds, e.g. like wrapping the hash-functions in other functions that contain the post-conditions, or taking their modulo of the number of bits. While I appreciate any further workarounds for the above use case, please, include an explicit answer to the main question (i.e. "is it possible to check if a function has a certain post-condition?") too.
"No, it is not possible" is also an answer I can accept of course.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320127/checking-clojure-pre-conditions-without-running-the-function?rq=1. Pre and post conditions are metadata on the arglist, which is metadata on the var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [is there] a way to check if a var is a function which has certain post (or pre) conditions

Yes, building on [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320127/checking-clojure-pre-conditions-without-running-the-function?rq=1), we can do this:

```
(defn fn->pre-post [fvar]
  (-> fvar meta :arglists first meta (select-keys [:pre :post])))
```

And write a function taking a function var and a list form to compare to its `:post` condition(s):

```
(defn some-post? [fvar post]
  {:pre [(var? fvar)]}
  (some #(= post %) (-> fvar fn->pre-post :post)))
```

Then we can test to see if a function has a `:post` condition we expect:

```
(defn foo [n]
  {:post [(and (number? %) (<= 0 %) (<= % 10))]}
  (* n n))

(some-post?
  #'foo
  '(and (number? %) (<= 0 %) (<= % 10)))
=> true
```

This is a very brittle equality test. If you reordered the `and` conditions the equality test would fail even though both `and`s would be logically identical. You could make the test more robust if you wanted.

> is it possible to construct the post-condition to be checked parametrically?

Yes, but again this is going to be brittle/subject to same equality limitations above. In practice, the only difference is we need to specify the form as a kind of *template* and fill in the blanks before passing it to `some-post?`. We can define a function that will replace the symbol `N` in a form with whatever we want:

```
(defn parameterize-n [n form]
  (walk/postwalk #(if (= 'N %) n %) form))

(parameterize-n
  10
  '(and (number? %) (<= 0 %) (<= % N)))
=> (and (number? %) (<= 0 %) (<= % 10))
```

We can use this with `some-post?` like this:

```
(some-post?
  #'foo
  (parameterize-n
    10
    '(and (number? %) (<= 0 %) (<= % N))))
=> true
```

As an aside, `(<= 0 % 10)` is equivalent to `(and (<= 0 %) (<= % 10))` but I used your example test verbatim.